# Did you have issues using a Microsoft 4000 keyboard with your Mac?

Tags: keyboard, imac

When I had a iMac (about 3 years ago), I tried connecting my Microsoft 4000 keyboard to it and I remember that there were some issues with key mappings.

I do like Mac keyboards, but at times I like the more relaxing feel of my 4000.

Is it possible to make the keys match 1:1 so there is no difference between which keys I press for each keyboard?

Comment: Which keys did you have issues with? Changing the mapping of keys like ALT and CMD are pretty easy in System Preferences.  If you'd like to do mapping of media keys and the like, you may need to use a more complex utility like KeyRemap4Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

The only issues I had (on Lion) were with the Microsoft drivers not retaining their settings between reboots. It seems the drivers were vastly improved (no more kernel panics) since you've tried them; see [David Röthlisberger's article](http://david.rothlis.net/keyboards/microsoft_natural_osx/).

Other than that, I think the ergonomic part is well worth the trouble of getting the 4000 set-up properly. And with [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) you can get almost limitless customizability.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

this is quite a good fix:
http://calebhicks.com/2016/karabiner-for-sculpt/

worked for me on el capitan

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review